# Installing magento 2.4 issue

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

After running the composer command:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

I am receiving the following error:
**An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.**

and in the logs:

```
main.CRITICAL: No key available {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No key available at Development/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:255)"} []
```

Not sure why I am not getting the setup wizard.
I saw the same issue [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Error-during-installation/td-p/433220).
Can you share your thoughts why I am receiving that error ? Thank you

Comment: Any solution for this? I too got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try to install it manually without composer and see if it works may be its because magento does not support windows os

Comment: ohh, I m using Ubuntu 20 with Valet/Linux btw

Comment: I downloaded the archive, but i m still facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to install magento via command line with:

```
php bin/magento setup:install
```

Source: [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html#instgde-install-cli-magento)